# apply vlookup formula for variable no.of rows

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have an excel sheet in which the first 3 columns are a pivot table and whenever I refresh it, the no. of rows may change. Columns E,F,G,H,I use a VLOOKUP formula based on Columns A,B,C.

Since the no. of rows are changing, how can I make sure that the vlookup formula also automatically adjusts for columns E,F,G,H,I based on no. of rows of A,B,C ?

Attached is an image in which you can see that the formula didn't apply for last 3 rows and I have manually drag the cells if it were to work. [image]

Comment: @pnuts: As you can see in the image for Column E, it's based on some other sheet named " EQ shock sizes" which is fixed. Similarly for Column F,G,H,I

Comment: Is the problem in the formula references? Or just that the formulas aren't copied into the range E26095:I26098 ?

Comment: @MarkBalhoff: Yeah, the problem is that the formulas aren't copied into the range E26095:I26098.

Comment: @AshokVardhan How are you refreshing the pivot table? VBA? Excel interface (Ribbon, etc.) ? Other ?

Comment: @MarkBalhoff: It's VBA based. So I'm hoping that I can inlude the vlookup part in it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat brute force would be to do something like

```
' Just Refreshed Pivot Table
'
' Assumes variable ws refers to this worksheet
' Assumes your formulas start on row 2

ws.Range("E2:I2").Copy ws.Range("E3:E" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
```

Then put an if statement around your formula in column E (and similar if statements on the other columns):

```
=If(C2="","",VLookup(...))
```

You can always do a more robust way to determine how many rows are on the left versus the right. Or step through like:

```
For i = 1 to ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If(ws.Cells(i,3).Value = "")
        ws.Range("E" & i & ":I" & i).ClearContents
    Else
        '''  Apply your formulas / values in columns E through I of row i
    End If
Next i
```